# Ошибка индекса на скобке

Tags: c#, массивы, index

Что делать, если ide выдает ошибку на скобке, хотя индексов на ней нет

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button xbut = sender as Button;
        if (xbut.Text == "" && this.queue == "one") { xbut.Text = "X"; xbut.AccessibleName = "1"; }
        if (xbut.Text == "" && this.queue == "two") { xbut.Text = "O"; xbut.AccessibleName = "2"; }
        if (GameMode == 0)
        {
            if (this.queue == "two") this.queue = "one";
            else if (this.queue == "one") this.queue = "two";
        }

        char[] value = xbut.AccessibleDescription.ToArray();
        VirGameBox[Convert.ToByte(value[0]), Convert.ToByte(value[1])] = Convert.ToByte(xbut.AccessibleName);

        //if (ChekWin() == true)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("Player " + queue + " Win!!");
        //    Rest_button_Click(null, null);
        //}


    }
```

Ошибка: `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."`

Место ошибки: Последняя скобка "`}`"

Comment: `xbut.AccessibleDescription` две цифры идущие подрят например "01" или "22" (цифры от 0 до 2)

Comment: `VirGameBox` массив из byte размером `[3,3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee6e613x(v=vs.110).aspx

`Convert.ToByte(char)` работает не так, как Вы думаете.

> This method returns an unsigned byte value that represents the numeric
>   code of the Char object passed to it
>
> Метод возвращает ... код символа

Вам нужно `Byte.Parse` -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ну если я 0 или 1 или 2 перевожу в byte то значение остаеться тоже

Comment: щас попробую и отпишусь

Comment: Все спасибо, заработало

Comment: @SovaNight На здоровье. Галочка - слева от ответа. Успехов!

Comment: Еще 3 минуты ждать чтобы можно было